# How are the basic Delphi types related to each other?

Tags: delphi, types

Delphi has long supported a few basic numeric types and I was wondering how they are related to each other.

In Delphi 2007 I found these declarations (some are conflicting, some are mere aliasses) :

Types.pas:

```
DWORD = LongWord;
Largeint = Int64;
```

getmem.inc:

```
DWORD = Integer;
```

Windows.pas:

```
DWORD = Types.DWORD;
SHORT = Smallint;
UINT = LongWord;
ULONG = Cardinal;
LONGLONG = Int64;
TLargeInteger = Int64;
ULONGLONG = UInt64;
```

This leads me into thinking the base signed numeric types are SmallInt, Integer and Int64. Unsigned, there's Byte, WORD and UInt64. But what is the difference between Cardinal and LongWord? (By the way, what's the original and intended casing for these types?)

And is there a type for signed 8 bit integers (Int8)?

```
// Int8 = ?unknown?;
UInt8 = Byte;
Int16 = SmallInt;
UInt16 = Word;
Int32 = Integer;
UInt32 = LongWord;
// Int64 already exists
// UInt64 already exists
```

Lastly, how should I define Int and UInt, especially with regard to C/C++ compatibility and a future switch to other platforms (possibly also 64 bit)? (A related question is, of course, how will the various numeric types be defined in 64-bit Delphi?)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments - what I've learned from this is, that the basic types like UInt8 and all variants should have been used as, well, the basics!

It would be nice if one future Delphi (or FPC) version turned it's type declarations around, so that the not-so-basic types are clearly derived from the basics.
I would expect to see something like this in Types.pas or System.pas :
  type Integer = {$IFDEF CPU64} Int64 {$ELSE} Int32 {$ENDIF};

Just my 5 cents, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signed one-byte integer type is `ShortInt`. You can remember its size by the fact that it's *not* the same size as usual C implementations of the `short` type.

As for capitalization, capitalize the first letter. [The documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/simpletypes_xml.html) tends to leave the "int" part at the end lowercase, as in *Longint*, but I think it's more common to capitalize it. Don't write the types in all capitals unless you're using Platform SDK types *and* you want your code to show its C roots; otherwise I'd just write `Word` and `DWord`, `Long` and `ULong`, etc.)

Delphi 2009, perhaps earlier, already defines types like [`Int8`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Int8.html) and [`UInt32`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_UInt32.html). As for how to define `Int` and `UInt`, I'd say *don't*. The language you're using already defines `Integer` and `Cardinal`; don't introduce new type names when you don't have to. Keep the names you already have, and then everyone else will know what you're talking about. (Besides, [`Int`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Int.html) is already a function in the *System* unit.)

<s>Use `Cardinal` when you want an unsigned type and don't care about its size; use `LongWord` when the variable must be exactly four bytes. Likewise for `Integer` and `LongInt`.</s> Use `Cardinal` when you want a four-byte unsigned type; use `LongWord` when you want a generic unsigned type and don't care about the size. Likewise for `Integer` and `LongInt`, nowadays. If you're writing 16-bit code, use `LongInt` when you need four bytes and use `Integer` when you don't care about the size; `Cardinal` and `LongWord` didn't exist in Delphi's and Turbo Pascal's 16-bit days.

The common wisdom for years had been that `Integer` and `Cardinal` would become 64-bit types on a 64-bit compiler, but that is apparently not the case. Instead, [they will remain 32-bit types](http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.non-technical/browse_thread/thread/86ca427823685b4a/ba5812a4e75fffa7?q=#ba5812a4e75fffa7), just as their counterparts in Microsoft C++ do. Furthermore, there will be a new type, `NativeInt`, which will be a 64-bit type in a 64-bit compiler. The `LongInt` and `LongWord` types will become 64-bit types because they have always been the same size as the `Pointer` type, which was 32 bits even in 16-bit times.

Comment: "The LongInt and LongWord types will become 64-bit types".  That's something that was discussed and no consensus was found, especially because they were advertised as the non-generic 32 bit types since the TurboPASCAL days. And Pointers in the 16 bit land where 20 bit large not 32 bit: "(Seg16 << 4) + Ofs16)"

Comment: Pointers were 32 bits in the sense that SizeOf(Pointer) = 4. It has never been the case that SizeOf(Pointer) = 2.5.

Comment: ... and integer was 16-bit in TP.

Comment: I doubt longint (and longword) will be 64-bit. Most OSes nowadays are LP64 or LLP64, not ILP64.  Though some more rare ones (AIX iirc) are.

Comment: Hey, I'm just going off of what CodeGear employee Allen Bauer wrote in the newsgroup thread I linked to. Andreas apparently also works for CodeGear, so he knows better than I what's really going on (which evidently is nothing, yet). If LongInt were 64 bits and Integer remained at 32, then that would be LP64. I now understand that ILP64 isn't very popular, but I think for several years most people naturally expected Delphi's Integer to grow to 64 bits just like it had grown to 32 bits before. (Wikipedia says AIX is LP64.)

Comment: Windows XP/x64 is from 2005, (and FPC is 64-bit since +/- that time) Windows XP/Itanium from 2001,  Linux/64-bit on Alpha already did all this in the nineties (and btw managed to run in a surprising 32MB at the time).  The URL to groups is broken, so I can't see from what date that is, but it certainly was visible a long time. Btw, the article I based myself on back in 2003-2004 was much alike http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html It mentions Cray now as example of ILP64.

Comment: @Marco, the newsgroup thread is from March 18, 2008, specifically message ID `47d95774$1@newsgroups.borland.com`.

Comment: Well, in October he had already seen the light: https://forums.codegear.com/message.jspa?messageID=23426 :-) Anyway, sorry to have pestered you, I just wanted to get to the bottom of these issues because I'm updating a FAQ.

Comment: @RobKennedy is there a broad consensus about writing `LongInt` these days? When I checked Delphi(4) sources, I saw both variants: `LongInt` (220 matches in 23 files) and `Longint` (3343 matches in 79 files), of which 18 files contained both forms. Even more shocking ;) in the official docs: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Longint (`Longint` in the title and `LongInt` in text)

Answer (score 5):

```
UInt8 = Byte
Int8 = ShortInt
UInt16 = Word
Int16 = SmallInt
UInt32 = LongWord
Int32 = LongInt
UInt64 = UInt64
Int64 = Int64

int = Integer
uint = Cardinal

NativeInt (generic, depends on CPU register size)
NativeUInt (generic, depends on CPU register size)
```

Cardinal and Integer are generic types. For 16 bit they were 16 byte large and for 32 bit they are 32 bit large. For 64 bit the Windows 64bit platform ([LLP64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384083(VS.85).aspx)) defines them as 32 bit. The new NativeInt and NativeUInt types are now the CPU register sized types.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning LLP64, which led me to this article : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#Specific_data_models

Amazing how much stuff one can forget... ;-)

Comment: FPC defines 64-bit unsigned as QWORD.

Answer (score 3):

Cardinal and Integer are aliases.

```
Cardinal ==> LongWord  (unsigned)
Integer  ==> LongInt   (signed)
```

[image]

Comment: Wrong! LongWord = cardinal = DWORD = **unsigned** 32-bit integer,

Comment: Whoops, had the intermediate names reversed (fixed). The outer idea is correct `Integer` is an alias for an `Int32`, `Cardinal` is an alias for a `UInt32` (to use the clearer .NET terminology)

Answer (score 2):

To get "the original and intended casing" press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd> after you typed a type name (i.e. use code completion).