# InnoSetup: Check .NET Framework - installation not working

Tags: .net, inno-setup, .net-framework-version, inno-download-plugin

Hi I am trying to integrate .NET Framework version check and auto-install in my Inno Setup script.

I am using the code I found here: [.../installing-net-framework-4-5-automatically-with-inno-setup/](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidrickard/2015/07/17/installing-net-framework-4-5-automatically-with-inno-setup/)`

The problem is, the code isn't working. The script compiles and outputs fine.
When I try to run the setup in a VM, everything works fine.

However, I don't see the .NET Framework actually being installed.
Just a quick 10 sec progress window showing various files being extracted (shown below).
Then it vanishes and my setup completes.

When I try to start my program, it reports .NET Framework isn't installed.

[image]

Here's the complete code:

```
#include <idp.iss>
function Framework45IsNotInstalled(): Boolean;
    var
        bSuccess: Boolean;
        regVersion: Cardinal;
    begin
        Result := True;

        bSuccess := RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release', regVersion);
        if (True = bSuccess) and (regVersion >= 378389) then begin
        Result := False;
    end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
    begin
        if Framework45IsNotInstalled() then
        begin
            idpAddFile('http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=397707', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\NetFrameworkInstaller.exe'));
            idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
        end;
    end;

procedure InstallFramework;
    var
        StatusText: string;
        ResultCode: Integer;
    begin
        StatusText := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
        WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing .NET Framework 4.5.2. This might take a few minutes…';
        WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
    try
        if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\NetFrameworkInstaller.exe'), '/passive /norestart','', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
        begin
            MsgBox('.NET installation failed with code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode) + '.', mbError, MB_OK);
        end;
    finally
        WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := StatusText;
        WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstNormal;

        DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\NetFrameworkInstaller.exe'));
    end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
    begin
        case CurStep of
            ssPostInstall:
            begin
                if Framework45IsNotInstalled() then
                begin
                    InstallFramework();
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;
```

I tried breaking down the code and trying to find the problem. Unfortunately, I can't identify it.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So what happens, if you run `NetFrameworkInstaller.exe /passive /norestart` manually? Does it install the .NET framework correctly?

Comment: Show us installer log file (`NetFrameworkInstaller.exe /log c:\path\to\log.log`)!

Comment: Also note that you can [integrate the .NET framework installation into your installer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39247947/850848).

Comment: You're right. The log stated the setup failed due to insufficient disk space. And thanks for the integration link. Will look it up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright finally I identified the issue, and it's an embarrassing one. My VM didn't have enough space, but this error wasn't being reported correctly in the setup script procedure `InstallFramework`.

The condition `if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\NetFrameworkInstaller.exe'), '/passive /norestart','', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then` always returns `False`, even if the .NET Framework installation fails.

The correct way is to just call `Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\NetFrameworkInstaller.exe'), '/passive /norestart','', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)` and then check the actual `ResultCode` to see if the .NET Framework installation succeeded. In the original script, this `ResultCode`'s value was `5100` (not enough space).

So, I modified and fixed the routine accordingly.

```
procedure InstallFramework;
var
    StatusText: string;
    ResultCode: Integer;
begin
   StatusText := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
   WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing .NET Framework 4.5.2. This might take a few minutes...';
   WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;

   try
       Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\NetFrameworkInstaller.exe'), '/passive /norestart', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
       if ResultCode <> 0 then
       begin
           MsgBox('.NET installation failed with code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode) + '.' + #13#10 + #13#10 + 'Setup will now terminate.', mbError, MB_OK);
           DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\NetFrameworkInstaller.exe'));
           Exterminate;
       end
       else 
       begin
           WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := StatusText;
           WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstNormal;
       end;
   finally
           DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\NetFrameworkInstaller.exe'));
   end;
end;
```

The `Exterminate` procedure aborts the setup (without a prompt) if the .NET Framework installation fails.

```
var
   ForceClose: Boolean;

procedure Exterminate;
begin
    ForceClose:= True;
    WizardForm.Close;  
end;

procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
    Confirm:= not ForceClose;
end;
```