# Is it possible to enable clicking on Installing page while executing other application in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to know, if it is possible to enable clicking on the Installing page while execution of some programs in background?

```pascal
Exec(ExePath, '/SP /VERYSILENT /NORESTART /TASKS=', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

I have `TBitmapImage` on the Installing page and I want to have the possibility to click on that bitmap and open browser. I have the `OnClick` event implemented for `TBitmapImage`, but I want to enable clicking on the Installing page because it somehow blocks clicking like whole UI is frozen.

Comment: The UI is not frozen while installing. For example the cancel button works all the time. The UI frozen only during some specific actions, like when you are running another program.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, you are totally right, I call in the background execution of some programs. Something like this:

Exec(ExePath, '/SP /VERYSILENT /NORESTART /TASKS=', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);

Can I somehow enable just clicking on the BitmapImage somehow? I don't need to enable cancel button. I just need to unblock frozen UI.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think is there any reliable way to re-enable the installer wizard disabled during application execution.

But you can run your other application using Windows API instead of the Inno Setup `Exec` function. Then the wizard won't get disabled. For example you can use `ShellExecute(Ex)` like  here: 
[Inno Setup Get progress from .NET Framework 4.5 (or higher) installer to update progress bar position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39247947/850848)