# How to delay without freezing in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, sleep, pascalscript

Hello I like to know how can I delay a work (or a command) for a specified time in Inno Setup Pascal Script.

The built in `Sleep(const Milliseconds: LongInt)` freezes all work while sleeping.

And the following function I implemented also makes the `WizardForm` unresponsive but not freezing like built in `Sleep()` Function.

```pascal
procedure SleepEx(const MilliSeconds: LongInt);
begin
  ShellExec('Open', 'Timeout.exe', '/T ' + IntToStr(MilliSeconds div 1000), '', SW_HIDE,
            ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
end;
```

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892452/inno-setup-exec-function-wait-for-a-limited-time), but can't think how to use it in my function.

I like to know how can I use `WaitForSingleObject` in this `SleepEx` function.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a custom progress page (the [`CreateOutputProgressPage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createoutputprogresspage)):

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var 
  ProgressPage: TOutputProgressWizardPage;
  I, Step, Wait: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall  then
  begin
    // start your asynchronous process here

    Wait := 5000;
    Step := 100; // smaller the step is, more responsive the window will be
    ProgressPage :=
      CreateOutputProgressPage(
        WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Caption, WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption);
    ProgressPage.SetText('Doing something...', '');
    ProgressPage.SetProgress(0, Wait);
    ProgressPage.Show;
    try
      // instead of a fixed-length loop,
      // query your asynchronous process completion/state
      for I := 0 to Wait div Step do
      begin
        // pumps a window message queue as a side effect,
        // what prevents the freezing
        ProgressPage.SetProgress(I * Step, Wait);
        Sleep(Step);
      end;
    finally
      ProgressPage.Hide;
      ProgressPage.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The key point here is, that the `SetProgress` call pumps a window message queue, what prevents the freezing.

[image]

---

*Though actually, you do not want the fixed-length loop, instead use an indeterminate progress bar and query the DLL in the loop for its status.*

For that, see [Inno Setup: Marquee style progress bar for lengthy synchronous operation in C# DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45856503/850848).