# Pause Inno Setup installation?

Tags: inno-setup

In Inno Setup I execute another setup file using this code:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MySetup2.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: waituntilterminated
```

This setup file executes another setup file and closes itself. But Inno Setup does not wait for the second setup and goes to the "finish" dialog. How to pause the installation until this second setup is closed?

[Inno Setup Exec() function Wait for a limited time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892452/inno-setup-exec-function-wait-for-a-limited-time) shows how to wait for the process. But how to apply this during installation?

Comment: Start by double checking if the `MySetup2.exe` offers a way to wait for its child process. That's the only correct solution. What kind of installer is that?

Comment: I do not think it has wait until terminated function. It is a VSTO Office Add-in Installer.

Comment: I mean how was the installer made? Is it Inno Setup? (probably not) Install Shield? NSIS? WiX?

Comment: The first installer looks like it is just a program that runs the second installer.

Comment: So do you think it's custom made? Why don't you embed just the "second" installer into your Inno Setup installer, if you believe the first installer is useless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue. You need to use a VBScript to run the first installer and make it wait for both first and second sub installer. It runs the first installer and wait until it is closed. Once closed the VBScript goes to the next code which checks for the process name of the second sub installer and waits until it is closed. You run this VBScript in the Inno Setup. Here is the the VBScript code which you need to save with file extension **.vbs**,

```
on error resume Next

Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments
dim strArg0
strArg0 = objArgs(0)
strArg1 = objArgs(1)

Dim FSO, CurrentFolder
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
CurrentFolder = FSO.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

const DontWaitUntilFinished = false, ShowWindow = 1, DontShowWindow = 0, WaitUntilFinished = true
set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
command = strArg0
oShell.Run command, ShowWindow, WaitUntilFinished

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

if strArg1 <> "" then
    strProcess = strArg1    
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '"& strProcess &"'")
    Do While colProcesses.Count > 0
        Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '"& strProcess &"'")
        Wscript.Sleep(1000) 'Sleep 1 second
    Loop
end if
```

And this is the Inno Setup code which you put in the Run section (assuming you saved the VBScript file as *MyVBS1.vbs*),

```
[Run]
Filename: "wscript.exe"; Parameters: """{app}\MyVBS1.vbs"" ""{app}\MySetup2.exe"" ""MySubSetup.exe"""; Flags: waituntilterminated
```

> wscript.exe

Runs the Windows Script Host

> {app}\MyVBS1.vbs

The file location of VBScript file

> {app}\MySetup2.exe

The file location of first installer

> MySubSetup.exe

The process name of the second installer.